# can a software engineer be good at data analytics using statistics and R

Tags: r, probability, mathematical-statistics, dataset

I am a software engineer and new to R. I started learning but at many steps I end up learning stats concepts.

So I was wondering if it's a good idea for a software developer to move to data analytics.

I am scared that I should not give up after spending so much time in learning it. If anyone can share their experiences regarding this, that would be great.

My question is whether it's a good idea to learn stats and continue with it. I started with basic plotting only. So after it how harder it is going to be?

If it is going to get harder, will that be manageable for a cs background person. Or are there good data scientists out there who don't have any degree in mathematics?

If someone can provide any guidance or any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is always a good idea to learn new subjects. If you are an engineer, then you might have all the prerequisites such as calculus, linear algebra, optimization,engineering mathematics and I'm assuming basic statistics/design of experiments. You should be well positioned to learn statistics. I personally prefer applied statistics. Comp Science gives you tremendous advantage for handing **massive** data/parallel computing etc. So CompSci+Stat provides you tremendous advantage over the individual areas. Just my opinion.

Comment: I must add, that this is a highly opinionated question and thereby you might expect opinionated answers.

Comment: Software engineers do not have good background for statistics. In fact they have none at all. Unless you studied computer science and artificial intelligence and took a ton of math while in a college, which you clearly didn't. So, it's too late now. However, there's a lot to do for a software engineer in data analytics area, just make sure you stick to your guns.

Comment: I agree with @forecaster that this question is highly opinionated and, thus, formally can be considered off-topic on CV. Even if this question is OK here, it's impossible to answer it precisely, as it was formulated. While I tend to think positively about your perspectives, the answer cannot be generalized and is highly dependent on multiple factors, including one's enthusiasm, discipline, dedication, abilities and circumstances. Feel free to read [my relevant answer](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/742/2452) on the Data Science SE site.

Comment: @Aksakal how do you know if the OP "did not take computer science and artificial intelligence and took a ton of math" Software engineer ? Software engineering is a branch within a computer science with heavy math background such a advanced calculus, algebra, engineering math, AI, machine learning and so on ...

Comment: Excellent response @AleksandrBlekh at the Data Science SE post.

Comment: @forecaster, if you look at the [curriculum](http://www.wm.edu/as/computerscience/undergraduate/major/index.php) of a typical software engineering degree there's virtually no math. I've dealt with hundreds of them, they don't know math. The only ones that do are SW engineers whose degrees are not in SW engineering.

Comment: @Aksakal: Sorry to interrupt your conversation. You're right, but only to some degree. I think that you underestimate what dedicated (enthusiastic) people can do (learn) outside of their initial backgrounds. Having said that, despite being a SW engineer with a non-SW initial background (solid state physics, semiconductor devices and microelectronics) with 3 years of university level math, I feel that I don't know well (or forgot) significant parts of it. So, I do my best to learn (restore knowledge) as much as I can for various reasons.

Comment: @Aksakal, please take a look at the recommended [typical curriculum](http://www.acm.org/education/CS2013-final-report.pdf) by ACM to see how much math background that SE has. I disagree with your comment at one broad stroke that SE do not have math. SE all have to take advanced university level math at least the SE that I know of.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh, of course I'm only right to a degree. My conclusions are observations not based on OP's personal qualities, "flat prior", if you wish :) As a former physicist I can attest that the math we were taught is not the same as what statisticians learn here, but the overlap is substantial. I have no doubt that you'll succeed. Forgotten stuff will start coming back, you'll be surprised. SW engineers never knew math, and it's too late to study it after college.

Comment: @forecaster, that's not a typical curriculum. It's ACM's dream, and it's for CS, not SE degree. AND did you look at the example curricula there? The one on page 503 has ONE math requirement: MATH 200. C'mon, this is  joke! I gave you an actual curriculum from a decent college. I've worked with hundreds of SW engineers, their advanced math ends around univariate differentiation. It's a miracle to find a SW engineer with SW Eng degree who can actually take an integral. In fact, I never met one.

Comment: @Aksakal: Fair enough! I still disagree with your "too late" stance, not just regarding math, but as a general attitude (or I'm cheering myself up). Nevertheless, thank you for kind words of encouragement :-).

Comment: @Aksakal Interesting choice to cite William and Mary's CS curriculum as a "typical" curriculum and generalize it. Very good sample size and also William and Mary's is very well representation of CS curriculum considering that William and Mary is primarily a liberal arts university.

Comment: @forecaster, W&M is a decent college. If you don't like them take a look at JMU's CS [curriculum](http://www.jmu.edu/catalog/12/programs/cs.html). Now compare this to "applied math and informatics" degree's required courses of Russian federal standard [here](http://www.jmu.edu/catalog/12/programs/cs.html): real analysis, algebra and geometry, functional analysis, mathematical physics equations, discrete math, differential equations, operations research, computer modeling, game theory,  probability theory, math statistics, optimal control, numerical analysis etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to this free online course [statistical learning](http://online.stanford.edu/course/statistical-learning) and flick through the associated book [introduction to statistical learning with R](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/). If you are comfortable with that then you should have no problems.

Answer (score 4):

Think about how much you know as a software engineer -- how easy things are now that you have some experience under your belt, and how many dumb mistakes you made on the way to getting where you are. That's the path you have to travel to become a statistician. It's not any easier.

When I was at Oxford, getting a Masters in statistics, I came across my tutor one day while he was studying a page of numbers. Someone at Harwell had sent him titanium titration output from 4 different pipettes and wanted an analysis. This being Harwell, no one had told him what the actual problem was, since that was classified. So there was my tutor with four columns of numbers that went on and on for several feet of computer output. He showed me the numbers, grunted something contemptuous about Harwell and stabbed a finger about half way down the page. "Well, there's obviously something going on with pipette number 3 around here." I gasped. I was still trying to figure out whether an ANOVA would do the trick and if so, how I would implement the thing, and where I would start. I was amazed that he just new what the numbers were saying without running the analysis.

Fifteen years later, I was called into the production unit where I was working, on account of a quality problem. I scanned the log book for several months wherein were recorded daily test samples. "What happened in January?" I asked. Apparently, they had replaced a part of the machine and not done a recalibration. "Well, that's your problem," I said.

The point of this anecdote is not to boast about how "smart" I am. The point is that it took me 15 years before the work became effortless. It's not the analysis you can do with R that counts; it's what you can do without it. And that takes time. You have already invested in one profession. You could make the switch, but don't expect instant mastery.

I don't know whether you can become a statistician without mathematics. I had 4 years of pure math, including measure theory, before I saw my first random variable, so I'm biased in favour of math as a prolegomenon.  I don't actually use mathematics much in the day to day ... but it's there in the background, making sense of it all. Statistical theory rests on a lot of advanced math, but many people run packages without actually knowing how they work, and they often get sensible results. However, it's a superficial way to go.

Comment: My opinion, Domain knowledge on the subject is much more important than mathematics/statistics if you want to be a problem solver. Statistics and Mathematics in my opinion are merely tools that can be used as an *aid* to solve a problem.

Comment: To me, good data analysis is a team project.

Comment: Agreed. In specific example that you provide on quality control problem, a process control engineer who by training and practice would be able to identify the root cause of problem more efficiently than a data scientist or a statistician. I have seen a lot of places where there is misapplication of statistics when all you need is a good domain expertise.

Comment: To me, good data analysis involves no humans. I jest. ;)